# The condition in J.L. Lions' lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I am reading "Linear and Nonlinear Functional Analysis with Applications" by Philippe G. Ciarlet and I see the J.L. Lions lemma:
Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$, then
$$
v\in D'(\Omega) \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \partial_iv\in H^{-1}
$$
implies $v\in L^2(\Omega)$.

When I search this lemma in google, I always find someone say $\Omega$ is an open subset in  $\mathbb{R}^N$ with Lipschtiz boundary. I am wondering whether this lemma is related to the boundary?

Comment: What is $\mathcal D’(\Omega)$? And is $H^{-1}$ the continuous dual of $H^1_0(\Omega)$ or something else?

Comment: If you can read French I would suggest you to have a look at the original paper "Deny, Jacques; Lions, Jacques-Louis. Les espaces du type de Beppo Levi. Annales de l'Institut Fourier, Tome 5 (1954), pp. 305-370", chapter 1, sections 1,2 and 5,6. In section 6 there is a proof when $\Omega$ is star-shaped